# Ordered Tests in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I created an Ordered Test in Visual Studio 2008, which includes a subset of unit tests in the project.

How do I now run this Ordered Test (without running every other test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordered test appears in the test view as the filename you gave it. You can highlight it and run it by itself.